# Unable to load Ubuntu 16.10 after installing it alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10, secure-boot

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a Dell 5558 by selecting the option "Something else". At the end of the installation process I got the information that Ubuntu was installed successfully and that a restart is needed in order to use Ubuntu.

But after the restart Windows 10 started directly and when I checked the disk in Windows Disk Manager, I saw that the partition on which I installed Ubuntu was completely empty.

Comment: One possibility would be that you didn't install GRUB to the MBR of the disk the system is configured to boot from. Microsoft likes to pretend that NTFS and FAT are the only [file systems](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33552/htg-explains-which-linux-file-system-should-you-choose/) available and will ignore all others, so care must be taken to avoid using Windows Disk Manager on dual booting Linux systems.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably everything went fine ... Ubuntu uses the `ext4` file system and that's the reason why you can't see any content in Windows Disk Manager (Windows uses the `ntfs` file system). The reason why Windows booted directly might be that the system is in hibernation mode. To change this, disable hibernation mode, open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Also make sure that Fast startup is disabled - go to Power Settings and uncheck Fast startup - if this option is not visible, enable Show hidden settings. Then shutdown the machine completely, do NOT reboot. Now start the computer, boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as default operating system to boot. Exit BIOS, now you can select which system to boot from the GRUB boot menu.